# Style Excel cell by given HTML input - export

Tags: c#, html, excel, npoi, ironxl

### The Problem

I am constructing an Excel file and the input for the `Description` column comes from a basic `<textarea>` tag and can contain basic HTML:

- `<p>` paragraphs
- Bold - `<strong>` elements
- Italic - `<em>`
- Underline - `<u>`
- Strike - `<s>`
- New line - `<br>`

I want to display/render (if that is even possible) the HTML in the Excel cell. Example:

[image: Excel picture, description column, HTML input]

### Libraries/Nuggets

I am currently using the `NPOI` nugget package, version `2.5.3`. I don't want this question to be library/nugget specific. I am willing to change the Nugget package for a free or paid one if there is an Excel nugget that does the job. I took a look at `IRONXL for .NET`, but couldn't find such an option for styling an Excel sheet.

### My code

```cs
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;

var cellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyle.DataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("text");

foreach (DataRow dataTableRow in dataTable.Rows)
{

    IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(dataTable.Rows.IndexOf(dataTableRow) + 1);

    for (int index = 0; index < dataTable.Columns.Count; index++)
    {
        var rowData = dataTableRow[index].ToString();

        var cell = row.CreateCell(index);
        cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
        cell.CellStyle = cellStyle;
        cell.SetCellValue(rowData);
    }
}
```

The `rowData` is a string variable containing the HTML. Example value:

```
<p><strong>Hello bold</strong></p><p><em>Italic</em></p><p><u>Underline</u></p><p><s><u>strike</u></s></p><p>Plains</p>
```

Formatted:

```
<p><strong>Hello bold</strong></p>
<p><em>Italic</em></p>
<p><u>Underline</u></p>
<p><s><u>strike</u></s></p>
<p>Plains</p>
```

*Note:* I've tried to create a regex that will match each paragraph(`<p>.*?<\/p>`) and then check each paragraph element for bold, italic, etc with another regex that matches while there are no more matches for the given style. I've successfully split the string into its retrospective parts, but the problem is that in `NPOI` excel library there is only an option to set a style for Excel cell globally. For instance, the whole cell will be bold or italic, while I want parts of the cell to be bold, italic, strike-through, etc.